# Transcoding arrays in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: json, azure, azure-stream-analytics

Let's say i have the following JSON data structure coming into Stream Analytics (generated by an IoT device):

```
{
    "user":"bob",
    "messages":[
    {
        "mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF",
        "data":[
            {
                "messagetype1":{
                    "param1":83,
                    "param2":82
                },
                "messagetype2":{
                    "param3":83,
                    "param4":82
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Above you can see that the data array contains named objects. I need to store the object name as well as the other parameters. Is there a built-in function to access the object name of an array element? messagetype1 and messagetype2 are just examples.

E.g.I would like to store:

```
{ "user":"bob", "mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "type":"messagetype1", "param1":83}
{ "user":"bob", "mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "type":"messagetype1", "param2":82}
{ "user":"bob", "mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "type":"messagetype2", "param3":83}
{ "user":"bob", "mac":"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF", "type":"messagetype2", "param4":82}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to deal with this is probably use [JavaScript UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

Though one can usually get away with some combination of [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt270219.aspx) and [Record](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt270223.aspx) functions tied up via [CROSS APPLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn706229.aspx), in your case the complication is with unwrapping different `messagetype*` records. You will need to know the set of all possible `param*` names to craft correct query. Alternatively you can use `GetRecordProperties`, but then instead of desired `{ ... "param1":83}` structure you will end up with `{... "field_name":"param1", "field_value":83}` structure.

Comment: Hi, I was not aware of user defined functions in Azure. I think that this should work. Thank you very much.